# Mirroring a map item in QGIS Print Layouts

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

Is it possible to mirror a Map Item in a Print Layout and if so, how?

By mirroring I do not mean a 180° rotation but an actual mirroring e.g. along the horizontal or vertical axis so e. g. east and west would be switched.

Comment: That seems really not common. I have curiosity what is it for ? I haven't done it. I think you can do a post processing but all the label will be also mirored, or to define a custom map projection that you use only for printing composer... But defining projection seems to be hard way.

Answer (score 2):

### Principles

You have projection rules that define what your coordinates significate. You can define your own projection and coordinate system that will have other rules.

The goal is to define a projection that will be East in the left-hand side.  Keep all your data source in the projection they are defined in.

### Step by step

First : go to project properties thatn project coordinate reference system. Select the projection you want to use as basis and copy the definition :

For EPSG 3857 it is something like that

```
WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
WKT
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting (X)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World - 85°S to 85°N"],
        BBOX[-85.06,-180,85.06,180]],
    ID["EPSG",3857]]
Proj4
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
Extent
-180.00, -85.06, 180.00, 85.06
```

Then create your own projection that you will only use for printing only.

[image]

You can name it `Miror print` and then to define it there is two possibility :

- Use the proj definition you choose and add `+axis=wnu`
- Use the WKT definition you choose and change `"easting (X)",east` to be `"westing",west`

Then your projection have a name you just have to go to print composer, select your map and set the CRS to be the one you create and :tada

[image]

### Final projection definition for 3857 inverted

The 3857 mirrored have this definition

```
WKT
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["westing",west,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Proj4
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs
Extent
Extent not known
```

Comment: Oh wow, that is one nice answer and very educative, thank you! Unfortunately it is too complex for my use case (which is just silly graphical stuff). I am looking for something as easy as the rotation feature but maybe it just does not exist.

Comment: If you let me know the EPSG of the projection you use i could adapt this to your use cas and you will just have to copy paste with no hassle.

Comment: Nah, thanks though! I'd need it to work with any arbitrary map, it really is a problem on the layout level, not the map projection. :}

Comment: I get an error when trying either the WKT or proj4 options ("Cannot save Mirror Print the definition is equivalent to EPSG:3857". It validates - just won't save. Proj4 used: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs +axis=wnu

Comment: Hello @Georgeofalltrades I have added the definition of 3857 mirored on the answer.